# How to read from keyboard in Io language?

Tags: io, iolanguage

I simply can't find the way to read from the keyboard.

Inside the script file, I tried with this:

```
CLI run
CLI setPrompt
CLI readLine
CLI whatever
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, a way of reading from a line that doesn't require you have `libreadline` installed, is to use:

`myInputtedValue := File standardInput readLine`

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
myInputtedValue := ReadLine readLine
```